# What exactly is re rendering and what is the flow of useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am learning react and I have been struck in understanding the flow of useState and useEffect hooks(how do they re-render the component) and what exactly does re rendering a component mean(Will the whole function be run again or how does it happen).I am attaching a demo code below it would be great if you explain how the hooks work in this case.

```
const [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState(0);
let inc2=1;

function increment() {
setMyNumber(myNumber + 1);
inc2++;
console.log(inc2);
}

return (
  <div>
  <p>{inc2}</p>
  <p>{myNumber}</p>
  <button onClick={increment}>Increment!</button>
  <p>{inc2}</p>
 </div>

 );
 }
```

Here once I click the button setMyNumber triggers a re-render right?So

1. Will it trigger re render in the middle of the function execution?
   2)If it re renders at the end shouldn't the inc2 value be updated on the screen because when I print it on console it is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state of the component helps us to indicate to react how the component should be displayed.

React has a "copy" of your dom called **virtual dom** and when the state changes, using the function returned by `useState`, react re-renders the componen wich means that the **whole function** of the component **executes again** and then react compares the new dom with the virtual dom, if there is some change then react updates the screen.

In your component the `inc2` variable is declared again in every render and is initialized with 1, but `myNumber` is just initialized with 0 only once and won't be initialized again in the future renders, to change its value you must use the `setMyNumber` func. You can do something like:

```
myNumber = 1
```

But react does not know that the state changed and won't refresh the page, that's why you should use the `setMyNumber` to let to react know that has to re-valuate the component.

The useEffect hook is useful to handle side effects, to understand this hook i recommend you this article
https://medium.com/@dev_abhi/useeffect-what-when-and-how-95045bcf0f32

Answer (score 0):

> Will it trigger re render in the middle of the function execution?

When React can tell that the function running is from inside React - such as a JSX click handler - it will optimize performance by waiting to re-render until the handler (and other work) is finished. This means that if multiple state setters are called, they can all be consolidated into a single re-render at the end, rather than one re-render for each state setter call.

If React can't tell that the function is inside React - such as directly inside a `setTimeout` - then it will re-render immediately, because React doesn't know when whatever processing is going on will finish. But -

> 2)If it re renders at the end shouldn't the inc2 value be updated on the screen because when I print it on console it is updated.

No matter when the re-render occurs, your `increment` function has scope of the `myNumber` as it was *at that time the component was rendered*. Re-rendering the component doesn't call `increment` again. The `increment` function [has a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the state value at the same time the handler was defined. So if `myNumber` contains some value at the time the handler is defined, and that handler runs, that handler will continue to see `myNumber` as containing that value throughout its execution, no matter whether or when a state setter is called inside.

Comment: I think I didn't frame the second one properly. My intention was ,lets consider all this code was in a component named Index.Now that my state is updated 1)Will react run through my entire component updating the variables that have been changed or does it just know what variables to update and it somehow goes to those lines in the component and updates them.

Comment: The whole component will start executing from the start again, and the different calls to `useState` will return the new values that are in state. Eventually, the JSX will be returned, at which point [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) will eventually result in React being able to determine which elements need to be altered/added/deleted in the actual DOM (which is a very optimized process).

Comment: Because in the above code inc2 is updated but why doesn't react update it in the webpage and after a re render why is its value setback to 1.This was asked before I saw your new comment.

Comment: `inc2` is not in state. Every time there's a render, it's initialized to 1. Even if you alter it inside a handler, that won't have any effect because that render is finished and a new render will occur shortly, running the function again and running the line `let inc2=1;` again.